# Ionic 2 - firebase plugin - not able to get phone's token

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2

I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase I have a button on the home.html that calls a test() function in home.ts

```
public test(): void {
    // wrap in the platform.ready && platform.is('cordova')
    this.fcm.getToken()
      .then((token: any) => {
        console.log("token: ", token);
      });
    this.fcm.onTokenRefresh()
      .subscribe((token: any) => {
        console.log("token onTokenRefresh: ", token);
      });
  }
```

By the time I am at the home screen, everything should be initialized and I should be able to get the token from getToken() function. But I am getting token: undefined in my console.log. I am not getting any errors, the log is clean, i.e. no errors are being generated regarding this particular plugin.

---

**Update 1:**

```
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController
    , public fcm: Firebase) {
```

---

**Update 2:**
Tried like this:
cordova plugin add https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase --variable ANDROID_VERSION=7.1.0 --save
But its still null.

```
private void getToken(final CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
                System.out.println("token: " + token); // null....
                callbackContext.success(token);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Above method isn't getting the token. So it seems this is not a cordova issue?

Comment: "Note that token will be null if it has not been established yet." It could be a server side issue?

Comment: ok. what does that mean?

Comment: No. How can this be server side issue, when I don't even have the token?

Comment: Have you set up your firebase to generate tokens?

Comment: There's no special setup that you have to do for firebase to generate phone token?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens maybe look at that. I apologize, I dont have much experience with firebase but I dont see anything in their docs that implies it is automatically generating tokens. I could be wrong, and if I am then there must be settings for the token generation so I would look at those settings and make sure that whatever automatic token generation is included in firebase is turned on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My google-services.json was wrong. I think I had created a new project but I must have not replaced the google-services.json with the new/current project's.